# I need to write a query in PostgreSQL which should match conditions of key value columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

Imagine a StudentDetails table in the below format

[image: Table Image with data]

Create table query

```
 create table studentdetails (student_id bigint,key text,value text, primary key(student_id,key));
 insert into studentdetails values (1, 'class', 'class1'),(1, 'city', 'city1'),(2,'class','class2'),(2,'city','city2'),(3,'class','class2'),(3,'city','city2');
```

Select Query

```
select distinct student_id 
from studentdetails 
where ((key = 'class') 
   and (value = 'class2') 
   and (key = 'city' and value = 'city2'));
```

My requirement is to fetch students from city2 and class2 (ie: student_id=(2,3)), but the above query returns 0 rows.

Note: I can not change the table structure.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregation.  Clearly, one row cannot match both values:

```
select student_id
from studentdetails
where (key = 'class') and (value = 'class2') OR
      (key = 'city' and value = 'city2')
group by student_id
having count(distinct key) = 2;
```

Th filtering on the students is being done in the `having` clause, because you need to combine values from different rows.

In Postgres, you can simplify the `where` clause using tuples:

```
select student_id
from studentdetails
where (key, value) in ( ('class', 'class2'), ('city', 'city2') )
group by student_id
having count(distinct key) = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since data of the same student are on multiple rows you can use a simple `JOIN`. For example:

```
select a.student_id
from studentdetails a
join studentdetails b on a.student_id = b.student_id
where a key = 'class' 
  and b.key = 'city'
  and a.value = 'class2' -- searched class
  and b.value = 'city2' -- searched city
```